# Measure scroll depth on inner content area with Google Tag Manager

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a site that uses a left-side vertical nav. We've added a Tag Manager code and are measuring scroll depth. Bu the TM code fires on every page load because we locked the body scroll and added a custom scroll to the inner content area to keep the main nav fixed on the left.

Any way to set up TM to record the scroll on the inner content area and not fire with page load?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Scroll Depth trigger calculates vertical scrolling depth from the top of the page to the bottom of the page. But if you might only be interested in knowing the scroll depths of a specific content element, such as the article body, you can **track scroll percentages of a specific content element**.

The way to make this work is to first calculate the height of the HTML element that contains the content whose scroll depths you want to track. Then, you need to check how far from the top of the page this element is. Finally, you need to tell the Scroll Depth trigger to track pixel thresholds that correspond with the desired depths of the content element, and add the distance to the top of the page to those numbers.

You can find details and the procedure in this article of Simo Ahava: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/customize-scroll-depth-trigger/